# How do I prove that delta - sinc function is the same as an (-1)^n times the sinc

Tags: sinc

$$\delta(n) - \frac{1}{2} \mbox{sinc} \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2} \mbox{sinc} \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)$$

The picture shows what I've tried 
[image]

Comment: I think your picture is wrong. $\delta(n)$ is only non-zero for $n=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Use the fact that, $\sin(-\frac{n\pi}{2}) = (-1)^n \sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}), \forall n \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: I am still failing to prove it using your suggestion. Please check my picture.

Comment: In your picture , in the end you are getting right result. What is the problem? I could not understand. Can you please give a little more detail.

Comment: I am sceptical because the graphs don't quite show it

Comment: $
\delta(n) - \frac{1}{2} sinc (\frac{n}{2}) = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2} sinc( \frac{n}{2})
$
\\Given that 
$
\sin{\frac{-n\pi}{2}} = (-1)^n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}
$
\\
$
\delta(n) - \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}} }{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$ = 
$
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{-\pi n}{2}}}{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$
=
$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}}}{\frac{\pi n}{2}}
$
\\
=
$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \sin{\frac{n}{2}}
$
can you confirm if that is true

Comment: yes this is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "show" rather than "prove". Here's how you "show" your equality using MATLAB:

```
n = -7: 1 : 7;

delta = zeros(1, length(n));

delta (8) = 1

Left = delta-sinc(n/2)/2;

Right = (-1).^n.*sinc(n/2)/2;

figure(1), clf, hold on

plot(n, Left, '-bo', 'markersize', 6)

plot(n, Right, ':rd', 'markersize', 9); grid on, zoom on

title('Blue squares = Left side, Red dots = Right side'); xlabel('n');
```

Comment: true! I corrected my question. Thank you for showing it, I'm still struggling to prove it though.

Answer (score 1):

$
\delta(n) - \frac{1}{2} sinc (\frac{n}{2}) = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2} sinc( \frac{n}{2})
$

Given that

$
\sin{\frac{-n\pi}{2}} = (-1)^n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}
$

$
\delta(n) - \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}} }{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$ =

## $
\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{-\pi n}{2}}}{\pi \frac{n}{2}}
$

$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \frac{\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}}}{\frac{\pi n}{2}}
$

=
$
\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \sin{\frac{n}{2}}
$

QED

Answer (score 0):

Hint: split it into two sequences: one for $n$ even and one for $n$ odd